# How to increase ViewPager swipeable area

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager with two Fragments. The first Fragment is a simple RecyclerView. But the second Fragment contains a full screen Google Maps element.

Fragment 1:

[image: fragment 1]

Fragment 2:

[image: fragment 2]

The problem is that when you are viewing Fragment 2, it's very hard to go to Fragment 1 by swiping from the left side of the screen to the right because the map will start moving. You really have to touch from the very edge of the left side in order to go to Fragment 1.

How do I extend the swipeable area on the left side of the screen when in Fragment 2?

I've tried adding a left padding to the map which does work but the layout gets ugly since the map starts after the padding.